# ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'IssuesGrid_OnItemUpdated' and no extension method 'IssuesGrid_OnItemUpdated'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, telerik

I created a gridview using Telerik asp.net/ajax controls and when I run the app locally the grid works fine but when pushed to my server I get the same error for all of my methods:

```
ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'IssuesGrid_OnItemUpdated' and no extension method 'IssuesGrid_OnItemUpdated' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have tried deleting the reference in the grid and creating it again and letting VS create the method and then it'll work until I do that for all of the methods throwing the error and then it starts all over again.

Here is the aspx page:

```
   <telerik:RadGrid ID="Issues" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" DataSourceID="GridSource" GridLines="None" Skin="Metro"
                AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" OnItemDataBound="Issues_OnItemDataBound" 
                PageSize="30" EnableLinqExpressions="false" EnableHeaderContextMenu="true" EnableHeaderContextFilterMenu="true"
                AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"
                OnItemUpdated="Issues_OnItemUpdated" OnItemInserted="Issues_OnItemInserted" OnItemDeleted="Issues_OnItemDeleted"
                OnItemCommand="Issues_OnItemCommand"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowStatusBar="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="900px">
```

And here are my methods in my cs file:

```
  protected void Issues_OnItemUpdated(object sender, GridUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {
                e.KeepInEditMode = true;
                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
                DisplayMessage(true, "Defect " + e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["ID"] + " cannot be updated. Reason: " + e.Exception.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayMessage(false, "Defect " + e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["ID"] + " updated");
            }
        }

        protected void Issues_OnItemInserted(object source, GridInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {
                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
                e.KeepInInsertMode = true;
                DisplayMessage(true, "Defect cannot be inserted. Reason: " + e.Exception.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayMessage(false, "Defect inserted!");
            }
        }

        protected void Issues_OnItemDeleted(object source, GridDeletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {
                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
                DisplayMessage(true, "Defect " + e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["ID"] + " cannot be deleted. Reason: " + e.Exception.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayMessage(false, "Defect " + e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["ID"] + " deleted");
            }
        }


        protected void Issues_OnItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName) //"Add new" button clicked
            {
                var editColumn = (GridEditCommandColumn)Issues.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn");
                editColumn.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.RebindGridCommandName && e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted)
            {
                e.Canceled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var editColumn = (GridEditCommandColumn)Issues.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn");
                if (!editColumn.Visible)
                    editColumn.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

What's weird is I have an ondatabound method that is just fine and worked before any of these problems started and continues to work. I tried changing the 'object sender' to 'object source' but still a no go.

Here is the OnDataBound event:

```
   protected void Issues_OnItemDataBound(object source, GridItemEventArgs e)
            {
                var gridDataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
                if (gridDataItem != null)
                {
                    var item = gridDataItem;

                    //Tooltips
                    if (!item.IsInEditMode)
                    {
                        var cell = item["Description"];
                        if (cell.Text.Length > 40)
                        {
                            var originaltext = cell.Text;
                            cell.Text = cell.Text.Remove(40) + "...";
                            cell.ToolTip = originaltext;
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be great!

Comment: Did you try deleting asp.net temporary files folder? It might be cached in there.

Comment: When you deploy, can you verify the dlls are being copied over?

Comment: I will try the dll's that is the one thing I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, copying the dll's over worked for me! thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code-behind (the `.cs` file) gets compiled into a `dll` when you deploy. Ensure that when you publish, these `dll` files are being copied over as well. This also means your published project should not have any `.cs` or `.designer.cs` files.