# ASP.NET Connection with Oracle DB

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

I do not understand why I have this error message. No code is used for the connection, only an SQLDatasource and a grid view. I am using this code:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
     try
    {
        using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("....."))
        using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from t1", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                 dataTable.Load(reader);
                 ListBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text=ex.Message;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code

Comment: try this.. [ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'IssuesGrid_OnItemUpdated' and no extension method 'IssuesGrid_OnItemUpdated'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21789125/990423)

Comment: I've edited your question to inline the image, but you **really** should type the text in the error message rather than posting an image. That way, others searching can find the relevant words in your error.

Comment: Here is the code I am using:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use *SqlConnection* for the Oracle!
First of all, you have to add *connectionString* into *web.config* to connection with Oracle.
Secondly, Add reference *System.Data.OracleClient* to your project.
Then, replace *SqlConnection* with *OracleConnection*. Everything, what you used with *Sql*, you have to replace with *Oracle*.

Comment: You left out how to change the provider name for the SqlDataSource. Probably best not to suggest a deprecated and unmaintained library. Oracle has an official driver that is essentially a drop in replacement for the built in one. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Comment: I installed this driver from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html
Then I tried to run the debug, which gave me this error. I wonder if I installed the wrong driver!
Also, I tried to modify web.config file but that step gave me an even worse error than this one. It could not read the file at all.

Comment: I replaced the GridView with a ListBox as in the script in the main post. The application is running with no errors now, but no data is showing up in the list. I am sure I am missing something but what it is?

Comment: <add connectionString="user id=database_name;data source=localhost/orcl;password=database_password" name="DNSOra" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>

Comment: and you have to change localhost/orcl to another one, if your database located in another host. If localhost/orcl does not works, try to use just orcl

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have install oracle data access client and then try this
   following code

   - protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string connectionString = "Data Source = DESCRIPTION = " +
        "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ho

     - List item
       st_name)(PORT = 1521))" +
       "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
       " (SERVER = DEDICATED)" +
       " (SERVICE_NAME = your_service_name)" +
       ")" +   ");User Id = ID;Password=Password;";
              Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection();
              con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
              con.Open();
              Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand();
              cmd.CommandText = "select ref_no from money_trn where ref_no=20170733";
              cmd.Connection = con;
              con.Close();
              cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
              Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              dr.Read();
              TextBox1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
          }