# 'default2_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'hfEmployee_ValueChanged'

Tags: c#, asp.net, hiddenfield

My question is about asp.net and hidden fields
Here's my error message.  I'm using asp.net.

'default2_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'hfEmployee_ValueChanged' and no extension method 'hfEmployee_ValueChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'default2_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can someone tell me how to fix this?  I'm new and don't know how to create a definition or fully understand what this is saying. Thank you.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551296/asp-net-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-buttonclick

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787935/asp-default-aspx-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-issuesgrid-onitemupdated-a